# c# Enum list Id values

Tags: c#, enums

I have Enum below

```
public enum IslemTipleri 
{
PoliçeNoDegisikligi = 1,
PrimKomisyonDegisikligi = 2 
}
```

If i use below code i can not reach 1 and 2 value of enum.Result displays twice text values not Id.

```
Array islemtipleri = Enum.GetValues(typeof(IslemTipleri));

foreach (IslemTipleri val in islemtipleri)
{
var result = String.Format("{0}: {1}", Enum.GetName(typeof(IslemTipleri), val), val);
}
```

Where i miss in code , how can i get Id values ?

Comment: asking for help in the comments isn't going to do you much good, just so you know.

Comment: just cast to int.  `String.Format("{0}: {1}", val, (int)val);`

Comment: @juharr answer please i will accept best answer if works thanks

Comment: See the linked duplicate...

Comment: Also please be aware that if you keep asking poor questions (3 of your 4 questions have negative scores) you will be banned from asking further questions. See http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints

Comment: Just so you know, the duplicate is the second result of a google search for "Enum.GetValue". Google *before* asking :)

Answer (score 0):

Add `int` cast to your code:

```
var result = String.Format("{0}: {1}", 
        Enum.GetName(typeof(IslemTipleri), val), (int)val); //INT
```

Comment: @Michael: I just run this in LinqPad and it produces: text: number